# Insert a value before comma in a file

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to create a simple program for login which reads/writes the information to/from a text file, but I'm having an issue.

Let's say I have the following content in a text file:

```
mytest@gmail.com, testPass123
```

First the email and after the comma the password. How can I read those two separately?

I have used `.split(',')` but it stores the whole line.

If I run this:

```py
email = []
for line in file:
    email.append(line.split(','))
print(email[0])
```

I get the following output:

```py
['mytest@gmail.com', ' testPass123\n']
```

Comment: "how can I read those two separately?" Exactly the way you are doing it here. You printed out the email and password as separate strings inside a list. What do you want the output to be instead?

Comment: Since you have a list of lists in `email`, if you want to print the first e-mail value from that list you need to `print(email[0][0])`.

Comment: i want to store the email and the password in 2 different arrays

Comment: didn't realise i had a 2d array....thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your variable naming is confusing you here. If you name `email` `accounts`, things might become clearer:

```
accounts = []
for line in file:
    accounts.append(line.strip().split(','))
for email, password in accounts:
    print("Email:", email, "Password:", password)
```

Comment: This way i get the account and the password together, but what if i want to compare only the password? I was thinking like 2 arrays, 1 containing the emails and the other the passwords, inc++ i was using getline() to store each data i read but in python i cant find a way to do that.

Comment: You now have an array with 2-tuples, basically the same thing.

Comment: Didnt realise that at first, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for multiple assignment

```py
>>> a, b = "em@ail, pass".split(",")
>>> a
'em@ail'
>>> b
' pass'
```